# Should licensing questions be allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, community-guidelines

I just saw the question about licensing ([Does Sitecore licensing affect API calls?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/636/does-sitecore-licensing-affect-api-calls)) on the sitecore SE site. As licensing is not an expertise of any of us and this may vary per customer, I would say that we shouldn't allow licensing questions over here and advise the person who is asking the question directly to sales support. What are your ideas about licensing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with this. I believe that StackOverflow and other sites take legal and licensing questions in a similar fashion, that it's not a proper question for the site.

Comment: Fair enough. I put in a vote to close it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the above, but we still need to make judgement calls on some questions. For example, I would consider the below to be valid questions for this site:

- Where should the license file be installed?
- Why am I receiving a license not found error even though it is in my Data folder?
- How do I view my license details from the user interface?
- How do I know how many concurrent users I am allowed to have?

Comment: Indeed, but those are more technical questions, not commercial

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I can see the argument. More so as I tried to answer it realizing that I needed to make sure we reflect it back to Sitecore sales.

I agree with this.

Answer (score 0):

I broadly agree with this, however the question cited in the example above seems legit, it's not specifically asking about pricing, it is a yes or no answer.

If the answer is yes then that it could affect the customer going into production.

Comment: There is no "in the box" EULA with Sitecore. Every license is unique to the customer which in it can and deos vary. Even if there is no technical limitation in the product, to may be against the agreement.  As a Sitecore rep once told me, "There is no such thing as a standard Sitecore license agreement"